# Cassandra returns variable results when looking for time series data

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql3, datastax-java-driver

When I give this query in DataStax DevCenter, 2 rows are returned. The rows returned are foe Dec 30th as they should be.

```
SELECT * FROM abc.alerts_by_type_and_timestamp WHERE alert_type IN ('Permanent Fault', 'Temporary Fault') AND alert_timeStamp >= '2015-12-30T15:00+0000' AND alert_timeStamp <= '2015-12-31T15:00+0000'
```

But running in PreparedStatement like this

```
    SELECT * FROM abc.alerts_by_type_and_timestamp WHERE alert_type IN :alertTypes AND alert_timeStamp >= :minTimestamp AND alert_timeStamp <= :maxTimestamp
```

returns below 4 rows.

```
    17:52:48,587 INFO  [stdout] (default task-39) minTimestamp: 2015-12-30 15:00:00.0 - maxTimestamp : 2015-12-31 15:00:00.0
    17:52:50,904 INFO  [stdout] (default task-39) row : Row[Permanent Fault, Thu Dec 31 12:09:22 PST 2015, 2015, 365, .....]
    17:52:50,904 INFO  [stdout] (default task-39) row : Row[Permanent Fault, Thu Dec 31 12:08:14 PST 2015, 2015, 365, ....]
    17:52:50,905 INFO  [stdout] (default task-39) row : Row[Temporary Fault, Thu Dec 31 12:09:22 PST 2015, 2015, 365, ...]
    17:52:50,906 INFO  [stdout] (default task-39) row : Row[Temporary Fault, Thu Dec 31 12:08:14 PST 2015, 2015, 365, ...]

    17:52:50,906 INFO  [stdout] (default task-39) count is : 4
```

I believe this is due to time conversion. Data is stored as GMT, but somehow PreparedStatement is passing it in PST ??

How can I resolve this issue ?

I also tried this :

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(minTimestamp.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(maxTimestamp.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
BoundStatement stmtByAlertTypeAndTimestamp = pStmt.bind()
    .setTimestamp("minTimestamp", new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis()))
    .setTimestamp("maxTimestamp", new Timestamp(dateTime2.getMillis()))
    .setList("Types", Types);
```

Printing out time on datetime :

```
 minTimestamp: 2016-07-19 17:00:00.0  
 maxTimestamp: 2016-07-26 00:00:00.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should change the file 
$CASSANDRA_HOME/pylib/cqlshlib/formatter.py

change function strftime to

```
def strftime(time_format, seconds):
    tzless_dt = datetime_from_timestamp(seconds)
    return tzless_dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')).strftime(time_format)
```

and import pytz library

i done this to change the cqlsh output to IST. You can change timezone according to your need

Explanation: Actually cassandra store the data always in GMT and prepared statements take the time in local timezone (system timezone) so your results differ in both query.

There is one more work around that you can pass the data time in prepared statement with time zone then according to me it should work fine

Hope it helps

Comment: How can time be passed in prepared statement with time zone ? I tried a couple of things and that did not work.

Comment: In which language you are using prepared statement ? I think the language will have support to do that or also you convert your time object to string and append '+xxxx' where xxxx denoates the time zone offset

Comment: Using java. I tried something like this:     DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(minTimestamp.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
    DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(maxTimestamp.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
    BoundStatement stmtByAlertTypeAndTimestamp = pStmt.bind()
        .setTimestamp("minTimestamp", new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis()))
        .setTimestamp("maxTimestamp", new Timestamp(dateTime2.getMillis()))
        .setList("Types", Types);

Comment: can you please comment the output of System.out.println(datetime.toString()) this will clear lot of things

Comment: are minTimestamp and  maxTimestamp your required timestamp ?
please dont change the input values in both the cases it is confusing i am not able to figure it out whether you are getting required timestamp or not

Comment: minTimestamp and maxTimestamp are required. They are passed in. Based on a range between these 2 timestamps, i.e. minTimestamp and maxTimestamp, I have to retrieve all the rows. Sorry I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: The value of these variables that you have updated in your question are these your required values? 
Please keep these values constant throughout the question you have changed from 2015-12-30 15:00:00.0 to 2016-07-19 17:00:00.0 which is completely different