# How to convert ZonedDateTime/OffsetDateTime to Date using ThreeTenABP?

Tags: java, android, threetenbp, threetenabp

Using the [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library, what is the simplest way to convert a `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` into an old-school `java.util.Date` instance?

If I had full Java 8 libs at my disposal, this of course would be the way to do it ([as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274369/how-to-convert-zoneddatetime-to-date)):

```
Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
```

But I cannot use that on Android; specifically [`Date.from(Instant instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) is missing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See `DateTimeUtils` which handles the methods added to classes like `java.util.Date`:
http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html

Edit: using that, the complete code would be:

```
DateTimeUtils.toDate(zonedDateTime.toInstant())
```

Comment: Nice, this utility class is what I had missed. So the exact code would be `DateTimeUtils.toDate(zonedDateTime.toInstant())`. Also good to note (looking at ThreeTenABP sources) that under the hood it uses just [what I had thought](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41480812/56285), i.e. `new Date(instant.toEpochMilli())`.

Answer (score 45):

Well, one straightforward way is to get milliseconds since epoch and create the Date from that:

```
long epochMilli = zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
Date date = new Date(epochMilli);
```

Feel free to point out if there's some preferable way.

Comment: or even a one-liner `new Date(zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli());`

Comment: @Sten's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72392825/1880761 is even simpler.

Comment: `Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());` is the simpler version from trebor's url.