# How to parse Datetime and associate it with the corresponding Timezone

Tags: java, scala, date, datetime, timezone

I am trying to read a String in the format `2019-12-23 13:35:00` to create a DateTime Object and associate it with a specific timezone to which I know it corresponds (GMT-5)

I am trying to do it this way:

```
 val string1 = "2019-12-23 13:35:00"
    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    sdf.setTimeZone(StaticDateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT-5").toTimeZone)
    val date = sdf.parse(string1)
```

The output is not what I desire, as it is not assuming the datetime is not in the GMT-5 timezone, but in my system's timezone (GMT+0) , adjusting the datetime to GMT-5 as such: `Mon Dec 23 08:35:00 GMT 2019`

How can I create a datetime object that does not change the input, and just associates a timezone to it?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Using Java syntax rather than Scala)

## tl;dr

> a specific timezone to which I know it corresponds (GMT-5)

`GMT-5` is **not a time zone**, it is a **mere offset**. A time zone has a name in `Continent/Region` format, such as `Africa/Tunis`. A time zone is a history of changes in offset used by a region.

You ***cannot* reliably determine a time zone from an offset**. Many time zones may share the same offset on a particular moment, but at other moments may differ. So you would only be making a wild guess. Apply a time zone only if you know the particular zone with certainty.

Instead, **use the offset** itself to determine a moment, without a zone. Here is a one-line solution.

```
LocalDateTime                                     // Represent a date with time-of-day but lacking the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone.
.parse(                                           // When parsing, no need to specify a formatting pattern when the input complies with the ISO 8601 standard.        
    "2019-12-23 13:35:00".replace( " " , "T" )    // Comply with ISO 8601 standard formatting, replacing SPACE in the middle with an uppercase `T`. 
)                                                 // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
.atOffset(                                        // Determine a moment by placing the date and time-of-day of a `LocalDateTime` into the context of an offset-from-UTC.
    ZoneOffset.ofHours( -5 )                      // Represent an offset-from-UTC with `ZoneOffset`, merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the prime meridian. 
)                                                 // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
.toString()                                       // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

[Run code live](https://ideone.com/B6j8D0).

> 2019-12-23T13:35-05:00

## *java.time*

### ISO 8601

Your input string is nearly in ISO 8601 standard format. To comply, replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2019-12-23 13:35:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

## `LocalDateTime`

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` given your input's lack of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Be aware that a `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. In your example of approximately 1:30 PM, we do not know if this means 1:30 PM in Tokyo Japan or 1:30 PM in Toledo Ohio US, two very different moment many hours apart.

### `OffsetDateTime`

You claim to know for certain that this date and time was meant to be seen through the lens of an offset five hours behind UTC (generally west of the prime meridian).

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( -5 ) ;  // Five hours before UTC.
```

So let's apply that `ZoneOffset` to get an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( offset ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/B6j8D0).

> odt.toString(): 2019-12-23T13:35-05:00

### `ZonedDateTime`

A time zone is always preferable to a mere offset-from-UTC. An offset is a number of hour--minutes-seconds, nothing more. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

But do not guess at a time zone. Apply a zone only if you know your `LocalDateTime` object was originally intended for that zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Panama" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, this was the most complete answer and pointed me to the right way!

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are using [JodaTime](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and then convert to `java.util.Date`. You can instead use `java.time` package from Java 8 directly:

```
val string1 = "2019-12-23 13:35:00"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val date = LocalDateTime.parse(string1, formatter)
date.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT-5"))
```

which gives:

```
date: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2019-12-23T13:35
res0: java.time.ZonedDateTime = 2019-12-23T13:35+05:00[Etc/GMT-5]
```

`LocalDateTime` produces a date without any timezone attached to it. The last line effectively creates a new `ZonedDateTime` from the previous date and adds the given time zone on top of it. If you need to go back to `java.util.Date`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32274725/2928853).

Answer (score 0):

- I would suggest using JodaTime. https://www.joda.org/joda-time/
- JodaTime is best working with the timezones.

For example, I have written a method:

```java
    public static Date getDateWithTimeZone(String dateString, String format, String timeZone) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date dateObj = null;

        try {
            dateObj = df.parse(dateString);
            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(dateObj);
            TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
            return dateTime.withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(zone))
                    .toDate();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.error("Error while converting string to date",e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

- You can change the method/exception handling as you want.
  Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). Its creator, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), went on to lead [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defining the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8+. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).