# Date conversion from 12:00:00 to 00:00:00 java

Tags: java

I want to convert:

```
 Tue Mar 28 12:00:00 IST 2016 time format
     INTO
 Tue Mar 28 00:00:00 IST 2016
```

How can I do it?

=================
 Actually
In the database, my date is saved with the format of "Tue Mar 28 00:00:00 IST 2016", I want to fetch this record using this date.but my following code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        return calendar.getTime();
```

but this is giving me **Tue Mar 28 12:00:00 IST 2016**, whereas I want **Mar 28 00:00:00 IST 2016**, So that it would be same as Database one, and will fetch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding n hours to a date in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581258/adding-n-hours-to-a-date-in-java)

Comment: Wait, is that really 12 hours ahead of time or is that converting from 24 hours time format to 12 hours time format? If the latter, don't forget the AM/PM suffix...

Comment: I update my question, wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) constant, which is used to operate in 24-hour clock, instead of [`Calendar.HOUR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // <-- here
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add 12 hours to `date` object, with `calendar`, e.g.:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = format.parse("2016-03-28");
System.out.println(date);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP wants to format the 24H time to 12H.

Try something like this:

`SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");`