# Adding time in hours to a date object in java?

Tags: java, date, time

How do i add hours to a date object. Below is my code:

```
String dateStart = timeStamp;
String dateStop = valueCon;

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

Date d1 = null;
Date d2 = null;

d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
d2 = format.parse(datestop);
```

I want to add 4 hours to d2 date object. How do i achieve it?

I tried to use :

```
Date modd1= new Date(d2+TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(240));
```

But it accepts only long object for adding. Thus failed.

Please support to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581258/adding-n-hours-to-a-date-in-java

Comment: Consider switching to `java.time`.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) it can be more helpful :

```
LocalDateTime dateStart = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime dateStop = dateStart.plusHours(4);
```

To format the date you can use :

```
String d1 = dateStart.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
String d2 = dateStop.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 5):

like others, i'd recommend using `java.time` if that's an option. the APIs are more consistent, and do a better job of catering to these types of operations.

however, to answer your question as-is... one option is to adjust the millisecond form of the `Date` instance by using `get/setTime()` as follows:

```
@Test
public void adjustTime() {
    final Date date = new Date();

    System.out.println("## Before adding four hours: " + date);

    date.setTime(date.getTime() + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(4));

    System.out.println("## After adding four hours: " + date);
}
```

hope that helps!

Comment: the question asked, and answered, was "I want to add 4 hours to d2 date object. How do i achieve it?", which clearly has nothing to do with parsing.

Comment: You’re right, I stand corrected.

Comment: Brilliant answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well there are several ways to do

**Using Calendar class**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates calendar
cal.setTime(anyDateObject); // sets calendar time/date
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4); // adds four hour
Date date = cal.getTime(); // returns new date object
```

**If you are using ApacheCOmmon Lang**

```
Date newDate = DateUtils.addHours(oldDate, 3);
```

**If you are using Joda-time**

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTime added = dt.plusHours(4);
```

**and if you are using Java 8 best would be LocalDateTime**

```
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime stopdate = startDate.plusHours(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- Never use `Date` or `SimpleDateFormat` classes.
- Use only modern *java.time* classes.

Example code:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(          // Parsing input string to an object without concept of zone or offset.
    "18/01/23 12:34:56" ,     // Input lacking indicator of zone/offset.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" )  // Define formatting pattern matching your input.
)
.plusHours( 4 )               // Add four hours. Generating a new `LocalDateTime` object, per immutable objects pattern.
.toString()                   // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-01-23T16:34:56

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ) ;
```

### Unzoned

Apparently your input lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "18/01/23 12:34:56" ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-01-23T12:34:56

A [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) has no concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So it does *not* represent an actual moment, and is *not* a point on the timeline. A `LocalDateTime` is only a rough idea about *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours.

### Zoned

If you know for certain the input data was intended to represent a moment in a particular zone, apply a `ZoneId` to produce a `ZonedDateTime`. A `ZonedDateTime` *does* represent an actual moment, a point on the timeline.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;  // Determining an actual moment.
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-01-23T12:34:56+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

To see the same moment in UTC, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

### Math

Represent a span of time unattached to the timeline as a `Duration` object.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 4 ) ;  // Four hours, as an object.
```

Add to your `LocalDateTime`, if not using time zones.

```
LocalDateTime ldtLater = ldt.plus( d ) ;
```

If using zoned values, add to your `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plus( d ) ;
```

Those classes also offer shortcut methods, if you wish.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plusHours( 4 ) ;  // Alternative to using `Duration` object.
```

One benefit of using a `Duration` rather than the shortcut methods is having an object that can be named.

```
Duration halfShiftLater = Duration.ofHours( 4 ) ;
…
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plus( halfShiftLater ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thats a beautiful answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(d2.getTime());
c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
d2 = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using JDK8 time API or joda-time if you can.
Old java api for date is so bad!

In your case, you can:

```
//commons-lang3
Date oldDate = new Date();
Date newDate = DateUtils.addHours(oldDate, 1);
```

OR

convert date to timestamp, add some mills and convert timestamp back to date