# Add time to string data/time

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, timezone

I am trying to pass a time stamp to my API that comes in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` but i need to manipulate the time to add 5 hours.

Have I done something wrong here? Do I need to convert it to a JavaScript date first?

```
var manDate = "2020-08-16 16:15:00"
manDate.setHours(manDate.getHours() + 5);
data.manDate = manDate
console.log(manDate)
```

Expected output - 2020-08-16 21:15:00

Comment: Refer this example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581258/adding-n-hours-to-a-date-in-java

Comment: Java !== JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a var for date, you need to add the 'new Date()' method.

```
var manDate = new Date("2020-08-16 16:15:00");
manDate.setHours(manDate.getHours() + 5);
console.log(manDate.getHours());
```

And to log the hours use getHour() again in the log statement.

Answer (score 1):

The question was asked to give a solution in java earlier. Below is the answer as per java.

```
Date newDate = DateUtils.addHours(oldDate, 5);
```

Comment: It's not a Java question, OP meant JavaScript apparently.

Comment: Also, at the very least it's worth mentioning that `DateUtils` is the Apache package, not core Java.

Answer (score 1):

Use simpleDateFormat to format the date, then cast the formatted date to calendar and add hours to it.

Try with below code.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfObj = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
sdfObj.parse("2020-08-16 16:15:00");                   
Calendar calendar = sdfObj.getCalendar();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
```